# Is a message queue like RabbitMQ the ideal solution for this application?

Tags: rest, web-services, websocket, rabbitmq, message-queue

I have been working on a project that is basically an e-commerce. It's a multi tenant application in which every client has its own domain and the website adjusts itself based on the clients' configuration.

If the client already has a software that manages his inventory like an ERP, I would need a medium on which, when the e-commerce generates an order, external applications like the ERP can be notified that this has happened to take actions in response. It would be like raising events over different applications.

I thought about storing these events in a database and having the client make requests in a short interval to fetch the data, but something about polling and using a REST Api for this seems hackish.

Then I thought about using Websockets, but if the client is offline for some reason when the event is generated, the delivery cannot be assured.
Then I encountered Message Queues, RabbitMQ to be specific. With a message queue, modeling the problem in a simplistic manner, the e-commerce would produce events on one end and push them to a queue that a clients worker would be processing as events arrive.

I don't know what is the best approach, to be honest, and would love some of you experienced developers give me a hand with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do agree with Steve, using a message queue in your situation is ideal. Message queueing allows web servers to respond to requests quickly, instead of being forced to perform resource-heavy procedures on the spot. You can put your events to the queue and let the consumer/worker handle the request when the consumer has time to handle the request.

I recommend [CloudAMQP](http://cloudamqp.com) for RabbitMQ, it's easy to try out and you can get started quickly. CloudAMQP is a hosted RabbitMQ service in the cloud. I also recommend this RabbitMQ guide: https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-05-18-part1-rabbitmq-for-beginners-what-is-rabbitmq.html

Answer (score 1):

Your idea of using a message queue is a good one, better than database or websockets for the reasons you describe. With the message queue (RabbitMQ, or another server/broker based system such as Apache Qpid) approach you should consider putting a broker in a "DMZ" sort of network location so that your internal ecommerce system can push events out to it, and your external clients can reach into without risking direct access to your core business systems. You could also run a separate broker per client.